# CfPrefrences error while writing to nsuser defaults in ios when app have data protection enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a ios SDK which synchronize user defaults while running in the background mode. The problem is the SDK is being used by the app with the data protection enabled and whenever the app goes to background our SDK keeps on scanning the beacon regions.

Whenever the device enter a beacon region I fetch a notification attached to that beacon from the server and show it as a local alert notification and while doing that I try to synchronise some data to the user defaults and if the device is locked with passcode at that point ios is throwing the crash:

> ****: CFPreferences: error creating file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/079820BD-EBFC-4C49-9C39-9A893A27358E/Library/Preferences/domainName.plist.gn1cmrC:
>   1  : task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with
>   error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)****

Any help to solve this bug by using nsuser defaults as a storage method will be very helpful . And if there is no way around then please suggest the data storage which is available when the data protection is enabled on App and the device is passcode locked.

Please note there are no errors when device is not locked using the passcode

Comment: I suspect you are using `NSUserDefaults` as a general-purpose data structure to share data between different parts of your app.  Is that true or not?

Comment: Yes, I am using app user defaults in my SDK just to store some strings and Array and everything works fine in the apps without data protection and if data protection is enabled and the device is not passcode locked . I just found this bug in the SDK today and desperately looking for a way around . The app is third party and they must be using the user defaults as well which I am not aware about

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` wasn't designed for that purpose and there are better ways to share data globally.  If the issue is in third-party code, then you should file a bug report with them.

Comment: Hmm but I think bug is in the SDK because App itself does't do anything while in background. What data storage are accessible when app have the data protection enabled and the device is locked using passcode ? And the strange thing is that writing and reading to nsuser defaults is successful even during and after the crash. The string I tried to update do get update in the user defaults.

Comment: *Data protection* enabled is not enough. Complete, Unless Open or Until First User Authentication? http://d.pr/i/1bmr3 By default it's Complete, can't access data when device is locked, ... Isn't this your problem? You can change it in developer portal, in place where you did create AppID. Just edit the AppID and change the level of protection if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the work around this by resetting the file permissions when the app enters in monitoring region, wakes up and is in background mode and when location manager fire the exit event for the region then place the permissions back . Code to do this..

App enters in region lower the file permissions to write something when device is locked by passcode

```
NSFileManager* currnetPath=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];
    NSString* prefPath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences"];
    NSDictionary *setNewDict = @{ NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone };
    [currnetPath setAttributes:setNewDict ofItemAtPath:prefPath error:nil];
```

and when app exits the region enable the highest data protection mode

```
NSFileManager* currnetPath=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];
    NSString* prefPath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences"];
    NSDictionary *setNewDict = @{ NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionComplete };
    [currnetPath setAttributes:setNewDict ofItemAtPath:prefPath error:nil];
    NSDictionary *newDict=[currnetPath attributesOfItemAtPath:prefPath error:nil];
```

Comment: Obviously that turns off protection for what might be sensitive data.